# Why does TextBlob 0.3.7 sometimes generate sentiment polarity of less than -1

Tags: python, python-2.7, sentiment-analysis, textblob

I recently started using the TextBlob package for Python (version 0.3.7). According to the documentation, the `.sentiment` method returns a tuple of sentiment polarity and subjectivity, with the defined range for polarity being between `-1` and `+1`.

However, this code gives me a polarity value of `-1.24`.

Is this a known bug or is there anything wrong with my usage of the code?

```
from text.blob import TextBlob
MyText = '''
tired of nbc universal. got 2 of the 3 periods of tonight's game and 62 of the 78 laps of the f1 race in monaco. stop the pregame crap and fill it with the event you morons!!!!!!
'''
text = TextBlob(MyText)
print text.sentiment
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in 0.3.7. There have been significant updates since version 0.3.7, including improved sentiment analysis, so I would update to the latest version (0.5.2 as of this writing). This can be done with

```
pip install -U textblob
```